# Hyperledger Fabric: How to solve "0 sub-policies were satisfied" when updating anchor peers?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Network configuration:

I have a Hyperledger Fabric network with 5 orgs and 6 channels. Each org has a single peer, and the orderer is part of one of the peer organizations (named PSU). All organizations are members of the channels "uam.psu.registration", "fuh.vertiport.operations", and "air.traffic.control". All channels except one (PSU) are members on the channel "fuh.financial.operations". All organizations except Fly-Us-Hospitality are part of the channel "vehicle.telemetry". Only PSU is part of the channel "secure.airspace".

Issue:

I successfully create all the channels and join the organizations to the corresponding channels without error. Then I try to update the anchor peers. For each org, for each channel it participates in, I run `peer channel update -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverrider orderer.psu.secure.airspace -c <channel_name> -f ./channel-artifacts/<channel_name>/<org>MSPanchors.tx --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA` where $ORDERER_CA is set appropriately.

It doesn't show any error message on the terminal, but on logspout I see

> peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com|2020-09-15 19:58:10.384 UTC [gossip.comm] authenticateRemotePeer -> ERRO 001 Failed verifying signature from 172.29.0.2:59660 : implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied

> peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com|2020-09-15 19:58:10.384 UTC [gossip.comm] GossipStream -> ERRO 002 Authentication failed: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Readers' sub-policies to be satisfied

For each `peer channel update...` command mentioned above. Any one have any ideas why I'm seeing this?

Here is my configtx.yaml file:

```
Organizations:
    - &PSU
        Name: PSUMSP
        SkipAsForeign: false
        ID: PSUMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PSUMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PSUMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PSUMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('PSUMSP.member')"
        OrdererEndpoints:
                - orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com:7050
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Boeing
        Name: BoeingMSP
        ID: BoeingMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/boeing.secure.airspace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('BoeingMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('BoeingMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('BoeingMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('BoeingMSP.member')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com
              Port: 8051

    - &Uber
        Name: UberMSP
        ID: UberMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/uber.secure.airspace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('UberMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('UberMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('UberMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('UberMSP.member')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com
              Port: 9051

    - &AirBus
        Name: AirBusMSP
        ID: AirBusMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/airbus.secure.airspace.com/msp
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirBusMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirBusMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirBusMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('AirBusMSP.member')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com
              Port: 10051

    - &Fly-Us-Hospitality
        Name: Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP
        ID: Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/msP
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP.member')"
        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com
              Port: 11051

Capabilities:

    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true
    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Endorsement"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    OrdererType: etcdraft

    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/peers/orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/peers/orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com/tls/server.crt
    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
    Organizations:
        - *PSU
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Admins"
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    RegistrationProfile:
        Consortium:
    GeneralChannel:
        Consortium: GeneralConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *PSU
                - *Boeing
                - *Uber
                - *AirBus
                - *Fly-Us-Hospitality
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    VehicleOperationsChannel:
        Consortium: VehicleOperationsConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *PSU
                - *Boeing
                - *Uber
                - *AirBus
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    FinancialOperationsChannel:
        Consortium: FinancialOperationsConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Boeing
                - *Uber
                - *AirBus
                - *Fly-Us-Hospitality
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    SecureAirspaceChannel:
        Consortium: SecureAirspaceConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *PSU
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
    OrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *PSU
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SecureAirspaceConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *PSU
            FinancialOperationsConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *Boeing
                - *Uber
                - *AirBus
                - *Fly-Us-Hospitality
            VehicleOperationsConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *PSU
                - *Boeing
                - *Uber
                - *AirBus
            GeneralConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *PSU
                - *Boeing
                - *Uber
                - *AirBus
                - *Fly-Us-Hospitality
```

And my docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: "2"
#networks:
#  network3.1:

services:
  ca-psu:
    container_name: ca.psu.secure.airspace.com
    hostname: ca.psu.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.psu.secure.airspace.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.psu.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.psu.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-boeing:
    container_name: ca.boeing.secure.airspace.com
    hostname: ca.boeing.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.boeing.secure.airspace.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.boeing.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.boeing.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=8054
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/boeing.secure.airspace.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/boeing.secure.airspace.com/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-uber:
    container_name: ca.uber.secure.airspace.com
    hostname: ca.uber.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.uber.secure.airspace.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.uber.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.uber.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=9054
    ports:
      - "9054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/uber.secure.airspace.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/uber.secure.airspace.com/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-airbus:
    container_name: ca.airbus.secure.airspace.com
    hostname: ca.airbus.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.airbus.secure.airspace.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.airbus.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.airbus.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=10054
    ports:
      - "10054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/airbus.secure.airspace.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/airbus.secure.airspace.com/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  ca-fly-us-hospitality:
    container_name: ca.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com
    hostname: ca.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-ca-base.yaml
      service: ca-base
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls/tlscs.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=11054
    ports:
      - "11054:7054"
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/tslca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-tls

  orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com:
    container_name: orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:2.2
    dns_search: .
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=ERROR
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=ERROR
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=PSUMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderers
    command: orderer
    volumes:
      - ../channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/peers/orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/peers/orderer.psu.secure.airspace.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com:
    container_name: peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=PSUMSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com:7052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com:7051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/psu.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.psu.secure.airspace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 7051:7051

  peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com:
    container_name: peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=BoeingMSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com:8052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:8052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com:8051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com:8051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/boeing.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/boeing.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.boeing.secure.airspace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 8051:8051

  peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com:
    container_name: peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=UberMSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com:9052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:9052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com:9051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com:9051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/uber.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/uber.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.uber.secure.airspace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 9051:9051

  peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com:
    container_name: peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=AirBusMSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com:10052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:10052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com:10051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com:10051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/airbus.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/airbus.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.airbus.secure.airspace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 10051:10051

  peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com:
    container_name: peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com
    extends:
      file: docker-peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Fly-Us-HospitalityMSP
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11051
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com:11052
      - CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:11052
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com:11051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com:11051
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/msp
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/peers/peer0.fly-us-hospitality.secure.airspace.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/crypto/peer/tls
      - /var/run:/host/var/run
      - ../channel-artifacts:/etc/hyperledger/channel
    ports:
      - 11051:11051
```

Before executing each `peer channel update ..` command, I update the corresponding environment variables:

CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=MSP

CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/peerOrganizations/<org.domain>/peers/peer0.<org.domain>/tls/ca.crt

CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/peerOrganizations/<org.domain>/users/Admin@<org.domain>/msp

CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:

Note: I am not affiliated with any companies whose name I am using in this network.

Comment: The error come from the configtx file ; the profile you are trying to update the channel with do not have Reader capabilities , but It's hard to see where the error come from... From where are you executing this transaction ? If I remember correctly, and with your congitx config , the anchor peer add transaction need to be executed on the behalf of the org you are trying to add the anchor peer to ,, so if you want to add an anchor peer to the boeing company , execute the transaction from a boeing peer.

Comment: @Popopame How can I make sure to execute the command as that peer? I have been changing all the environment variables like CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID, CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH, etc to match the corresponding organizations and then running all the peer commands from the shell. Is that sufficient?

Comment: In which environment are you working in ? if you are testing in a learning env , like docker-compose , I do recommend the creation of a cli peer , it will be much easier to interact with your network ,and most of the hyperledger fabric tutorial are made this way.  Now for the variables , if everything is set correctly , it should work , as in your configtx you authorize it , can  you list all the environment variables you set before issuing the command ? :)

Comment: As Poponame mentioned, @jnasworld223 could you share in detail the configuration of an organization? I understand that you are using docker-compose, so, could you share the docker-compose configuration for an organization (for example, boeing)? Could you also share de env variables and its value before executing the mentioned command? I understand that you are working with the 2.x version

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I using docker-compose to configure everything, and I am using fabric 2.2. I added the compose.yaml file and all the environment variables I update on the OP. 

Why do you recommend using a cli peer? What advantages does that have over running commands directly on the host system?

Comment: Can you add `BoeingMSP.admin` to `READERS` rule as well and try?

Comment: I initially had admin, peer, client and to the Readers rules for each org, admin and peer to the Writers rule for each org, peer and admin for the Endorsement rules for each org, and admin the same as above. This didn't work, so I moved to member for all rules except admin to be more generic in hopes it would fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing the `peer update` command, please check below `env` variables.

```
# change Org1MSP to your org msp name
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"

# here org name accordingly
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/users/Admin@org1.com/msp

export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PWD}/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.com/peers/peer1.org1.com/tls/ca.crt
```

Above values are for reference only. You have to check that they are pointing to correct path.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have been changing the environment variables prior to running each `peer update` command